# Identity Operator on Different Bases

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that if $B_1$ and $B_2$ are bases of $V$, then $[I]_{B_1, B_2}$ is an invertible matrix. What is its inverse?

Does it have to be invertible because there must be a matrix to convert from $B_2$ to $B_1?$ Would the inverse be $[I]_{B_2, B_1}?$ Intuitively this seems correct, but I'm not certain.

Answer (score 0):

Note that for any maps $F, G \colon V \to V$ and any bases $B_i$, $i=1,2,3$, we have
$$ [F]_{B_2, B_3}[G]_{B_1, B_2} = [F \circ G]_{B_1, B_3} $$
and for any basis $B$, 
$$ [I]_{B,B} = I $$
hence
 $$ [I]_{B_2, B_1}[I]_{B_1, B_2} = [I]_{B_1, B_1} = I $$ 
and 
 $$ [I]_{B_1, B_2}[I]_{B_2, B_1} = [I]_{B_2, B_2} = I $$ 
so  $$ [I]_{B_2, B_1} = [I]_{B_1, B_2}^{-1} .$$